# mapping an array of object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Anyone has an idea how to make this possible ? getAllData returns and array of objects I want to map each object result from the getAllData and get the id of object which type is Type-A , after getting each id I want to use each id to query on getDealDetails using the Id.

If id match and has result on getDealDetails get the TypeValues summary value from getDealDetails result and append new key value to res items from the result of getAllData , the new key is "dataValue:" and the value is the data from TypeValues summary

#final result would be something like the object below , since for example there is id match which is 248 then append the dataValue stated above.

Thanks for any help and idea.

```
[
        {
            "id": 248,
            "name": "248-A",
            "Type": "Type-A",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null,
            "dataValue": "Summary Data"
        },
          {
            "id": 249,
            "name": "249-A",
            "Type": "Type-A",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        },
     {
            "id": 243,
            "name": "243-Z",
            "Type": "Type-Z",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        },
    ]
```

my code pulling data and the res items

```
private getAllData() {
    this.searchInput = '';
    const status = 'Draft'
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.dealService
      .getAllData(
        status,
        this.accountId,
        this.transaction.id,
        this.table.pageIndex + 1,
        this.table.pageSize,
        this.searchInput,
        this.table.sortParams,
        this.table.sortDirs
      )
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log("ress " , res.items)
        this.getDealDetails(res.items.id);
      }, (err) => this.notificationService.showError(err)
    );
  }
```

sample result items from getAllData

```
[
    {
        "id": 248,
        "name": "248-A",
        "Type": "Type-A",
        "fileName": null,
        "serverFileName": null,
        "size": null,
        "absoluteUri": null,
        "sentTo": null
    },
      {
        "id": 249,
        "name": "249-A",
        "Type": "Type-A",
        "fileName": null,
        "serverFileName": null,
        "size": null,
        "absoluteUri": null,
        "sentTo": null
    },
 {
        "id": 243,
        "name": "243-Z",
        "Type": "Type-Z",
        "fileName": null,
        "serverFileName": null,
        "size": null,
        "absoluteUri": null,
        "sentTo": null
    },
]

get details code

     getDetails(Id: number) {
        this.service.getDetails(Id)
        .subscribe(
          res =>{  
            console.log("res.data;" , res.data)            
          },
          err =>{
            console.log('Error getting deal details');
          }
        )
       }
```

getDetails sample result

```
{
    "id": 248,
    "name": "248-A",
    "fileName": null,
    "serverFileName": null,
    "size": null,
    "absoluteUri": null,
    "sentTo": null,
    "TypeValues": {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "248-A",
        "summary": "Summary Data",
   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is take the result of the first query, then execute a bunch of additional queries to append additional data. I would suggest looking at the RxJS documentation specifically the operators: combineAll, concatAll, combineLatest

Below is an example of what you could do... Although I think there are other serious issues in your code example, like res.data vs res.items and trying to get res.items.id on an array...  below is psuedocode

```js
  private getAllData() {
   
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.dealService
      .getAllData(
        status,
        this.accountId,
        this.transaction.id,
        this.table.pageIndex + 1,
        this.table.pageSize,
        this.searchInput,
        this.table.sortParams,
        this.table.sortDirs
      )
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => res.items.map(
          // get details for item and append them to a new copy of item 
          item => this.getDealDetails(item.id).pipe(
            map((getDealDetailsResponse: any) =>
              ({
                ...item,
                ...{ dataValue: getDealDetailsResponse.data.TypeValues }
              })
            )
          ))
        ),
        // Combine the array of observables returned above into a single observable 
        // and return the result when they all complete
        combineAll()
      ).subscribe((mergedResults) => {
        console.log(mergedResults);
      });      
  }
```